# Inflate a child view in a recyclerview when getting data from Firebase with Android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Activity which get called when a user clicks on a FAB

```
public class PicksheetActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    GameAdapter adapter;

    List<Games> gameList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.picksheet_layout);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        gameReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("Games");
    
        gameQuery = gameReference.equalTo(1);

        // Add handle for listener
        mListener = gameQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    for (DataSnapshot gameSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Games game = new Games(gameSnapshot);
                        //
                        gameList.add(game);



                        adapter = new GameAdapter(this, gameList);  <--- Error here

                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    } 
       
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                Log.w("SurvivorPickSheetActivity", "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

            }

        }

    });
    
}
```

The GameAdapter class is as follows:

```
public class GameAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameAdapter.GameViewHolder> {

    public GameAdapter(Context mCtx, List<Games> gameList) {

        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.gameList = gameList;

        Log.d("CREATION", "*** CALLING THE GameAdapter class ***");

    }

    @Override
    public GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent,false);

        GameViewHolder gameViewHolder = new GameViewHolder(view);

        return gameViewHolder;

    }

}
```

The compiler is telling me to change the GameAdapter's class constructor from `Context` to `ValueEventListener` since I guess I'm making the call to Firebase

If I do that then the GameAdapter `onCreateViewHolder` wont work since the LayoutInflater.from() function requires Context and not a ValueEventListener to inflate the view?!

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> adapter = new GameAdapter(this, gameList);  <--- Error here

Here `this` refers to the surrounding class which is the anonymous inner class created by `new ValueEventListener() {` instance and it is not a `context`.

In order to refer to the outer class to get the context, you can replace `this` with `PicksheetActivity.this`